# Is there any way to imitate ThreadStatic for use with HttpContext.Current.Items?

Tags: .net, asp.net, attributes, threadstatic

Because of *Thread Agility* in ASP.Net, `ThreadStatic` is not an appropriate mechanism to use in web applications for segregating static property access from one request to the next.

In order to avoid lots of calls to `HttpContext.Current.Items` and the associated null checks and so forth, is there any trickery offered by the .Net framework whereby I could create an attribute which works sort of like `ThreadStatic`, but utilises `HttpContext.Current.Items` if the current code is being executed within an ASP.Net request context?

*note: I am aware that ThreadStaticAttribute is a special case with no functional code internally and is checked for by the JIT compiler before any of its magic is worked.*

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Segregate static property access between requests? Why does it need to be any kind of static?

Answer (score 2):

The n2cms project has an [AdaptiveContext class](http://code.google.com/p/n2cms/source/browse/trunk/src/N2/Web/AdaptiveContext.cs) built out which you might have a look at. I know there was some talk of doing something similar in log4net, but I'm not sure if that was completed.

Nothing built into the framework, though, as far as I can tell.